# As3 loading blank image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm having problems loading an image from an externall source (this was working but we changed the server to a https and made some adjustments).
Now, when I loaded the image, there are no errors, but the width, height are all 0. Also the image is blank. 
I tried loading with this script some random internet image and it worked fine. However with the original - (https://www.lovemarks.co/images/be50fe37eac192fb7c0d17353f5ef993a.jpg) - it doesn't work.

```
var somethingLoaded:Boolean = true;
var actualPic:*;
var pictLdrX:Loader = new Loader();
var pictURLX:String = 'https://www.lovemarks.co/images/be50fe37eac192fb7c0d17353f5ef993a.jpg';
var pictURLReqX:URLRequest = new URLRequest(pictURLX);
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
pictLdrX.load(pictURLReqX);
pictLdrX.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT , loadedRemember)                    

function loadedRemember(event:Event){
    var targetLoader:Loader = Loader(event.target.loader);
    var newmc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    addChild(newmc);
    newmc.addChild(targetLoader.content);
    newmc.x = -targetLoader.width/2;
    newmc.y = -targetLoader.height/2;
    trace ('w+'+targetLoader.width);     
    trace ('h+'+targetLoader.height);
    trace ('x+'+newmc.x);
    trace ('y+'+newmc.y);   
}
```

Comment: Are both served on the same domain? (And same protocol?) flash has cross origin restrictions. You have to upload an XML file to allow access. Other than that try using the developer version of flash player to check for errors.

Comment: Try listening for the myriad of events that could get dispatched when you load something. An example of doing so is given at the bottom of [this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html).

Answer (score 0):

The way would do it is to first listen for `Event.COMPLETE` instead of `Event.INIT`:

```
pictLdrX.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , loadedRemember);
```

Then, instead of referencing the actual loader in your handler, just reference the image directly by first casting the `Event.target.content` as a `Bitmap`:

```
function loadedRemember(event:Event)
{
    trace("loadedRemember()");

    var newmc:Bitmap = Bitmap(event.target.content);
    addChild(newmc);
    // Your math to center may need to be adjusted
    // to account for such a big image size
    newmc.x = -newmc.width/2;
    newmc.y = -newmc.height/2;

    trace ('w+'+newmc.width + '\nh+'+newmc.height + '\nx+'+newmc.x + '\ny+'+newmc.y);   
}
```

Additionally check for any security errors related to cross domain within your output window.